# What is the most efficient way to extract info from complex JSON files?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new to Python and am working on extracting certain information from dict files.

I have millions of JSON files that store text data. All JSON files have similar structures. There are a lot of variations in terms of structure. For each JSON file, I want to extract all of the text strings from a particular key and store them as a dict.

`json1` and `json2` below are simplified examples. What I have been doing is to take a sample from the JSON files, analyze them, write a lot of if-statements with an attempt to include all of the possible variations. However, I find it inefficient and am still not able to include all of the scenarios. I wonder if there's a general way to search and extract the values using the key `"text"`.

```
json1 = {
        "section": {
                   "heading":{"lvl":"A1", "text":"today"},
                   "paragraph":[
                                {"color":"green",  "text":"yesterday"},
                                {"color":"purple", "text":"tomorrow"}
                               ]
                   }
         }

json2 = {
        "paragraph":{"text":"everyday", "color": "black"}
        }
```

In other words, I want to get a dict that contains all the text strings with a key of "text." For `json1`, I want to get `{"json1":"today yesterday tomorrow"}`. For `json2`, I want to get `{"json2":"everyday"}`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a `set` or a `dict` as a result? you've shown a `set`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want a `dict` as the result. i have my description fixed. sorry for confusion.

Comment: Now you have a `dict` with the name of the json object as a key (strange) and a string consisting of every `"text"` value concateneted and joined by a comma... are you sure that's what you want? That doesn't sound particularly useful, especially since it's a dictionary with a single key-value pair...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know anything else, and the structure can be rather arbitrary as you imply, then you have to visit every node and check. This can be achieved in a generic way using recursion. Here is a quick-and-dirty function to achieve it:

```
In [4]: def extract_text(obj, acc):
    ...:     if isinstance(obj, dict):
    ...:         for k, v in obj.items():
    ...:             if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
    ...:                 extract_text(v, acc)
    ...:             elif k == "text":
    ...:                 acc.append(v)
    ...:     elif isinstance(obj, list):
    ...:         for item in obj:
    ...:             extract_text(item, acc)
...:
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
In [5]: acc1 = []

In [6]: extract_text(json1, acc1)

In [7]: acc1
Out[7]: ['yesterday', 'tomorrow', 'today']

In [8]: acc2 = []

In [9]: extract_text(json2, acc2)

In [10]: acc2
Out[10]: ['everyday']
```

Note, your question doesn't really have anything to do with JSON, which is a text-based data serialization format. You are already dealing with deserialized data and python data structures. In any event, if you really want the result you have in your question, you can simply do:

```
In [11]: {"json1": ",".join(acc1)}
Out[11]: {'json1': 'yesterday,tomorrow,today'}
```

Or whatever separator you prefer to join on, like a simple space:

```
In [12]: {"json1": " ".join(acc1)}
Out[12]: {'json1': 'yesterday tomorrow today'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know anything about the structure of the json files, I would suggest to dump the content and search in the list. A quick solution is as follows. It only assumes that `'text'` key corresponds to a one-word entry.

```
import pickle
import json

# Open .json file
f = open("myjson.json")
# Load the content
info = json.load(f)
# Dump the content as a list of words
info_list = pickle.dumps(info).split('\n')
# Whenever you see a 'text', collect the second next item
texts = [info_list[i+2][1:] for i,a in enumerate(info_list) if a.find('text')>0]
# Output the result
print texts
```

The output per json file becomes:

```
In [1]: texts
Out[1]: ['yesterday', 'tomorrow', 'today']
```

Comment: This is an extremely hackey and brittle approach. It relies on the `pickle` format being the same, and this doesn't work on python 3 as you've written it. For example, I cannot reproduce your results, and likely that's because the pickle is using different protocols. I'm on Python 2.7.12.