# How to extract text from the deepest level of a nested dict file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

This question is a follow-up question of [What is the most efficient way to extract info from complex JSON files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498645/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-extract-info-from-complex-json-files)

I have a ton of dict files which structure can be arbitrary. I want to capture all the strings with a key of "text," as well as all the strings with a key of "htext" when there is no additional nest.

```
d = {
        "section": {
                   "heading":{"lvl":"A1", "text":"today"},
                   "htext":[
                                {"color":"green",  "text":"yesterday", "htext":["a","b","c"]},
                                {"color":"purple", "text":"tomorrow"}
                               ]
                   }
         }
```

In the example above, I want my result to be `["today", "yesterday", "a", "b", "c", "tomorrow"]`.

The solution provided in the previous question is:

```
def extract_text(obj, acc):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                extract_text(v, acc)
            elif k == "text":
                acc.append(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            extract_text(item, acc)
```

I tried to modify this function by adding `k == 'htext'` to the `elif` statement but wasn't successful. I have new to Python. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {
        "section": {
                   "heading":{"lvl":"A1", "text":"today"},
                   "htext":[
                                {"color":"green",  "text":"yesterday", "htext":["a","b","c"]},
                                {"color":"purple", "text":"tomorrow"}
                               ]
                   }
         }

acc = [];

def extract_text(obj, acc):
     if isinstance(obj, dict):
         for k, v in obj.items():
             if isinstance(v, dict):
                 extract_text(v, acc)
             elif k == "text":
                 acc.append(v)
             elif k == "htext" and isinstance(v, list) and all([isinstance(item, str) for item in v]):
                 for item in v:
                     acc.append(item)
             elif isinstance(v, list):
                 extract_text(v, acc)
     elif isinstance(obj, list):
         for item in obj:
             extract_text(item, acc)


extract_text(d, acc)
print(acc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key is "htext" and the value is a non-nested list :

```
def extract_text(obj, acc):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
          if k == "htext" and isinstance(v, list) and not isinstance(v[0], (dict, list)):
             for x in v:
               acc.append(x) 
          elif isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
              extract_text(v, acc)
          elif k == "text":
              acc.append(v)

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            extract_text(item, acc)

#=> ['yesterday', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'tomorrow', 'today']
```